# Connect 5V DC fans to a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, dc-motor

I wish to connect four 5V DC fans (each one current is ~0.1-0.15A) to a Raspberry Pi 4. As I can not add another power supply (PSU) beside the one of the raspberry Pi 4, I was thinking to connect them directly to the Pi-Plates MOTORplate (https://pi-plates.com/motorr1/). Will it work? Any other ideas how to avoid two PSU?

Comment: *"I wish to connect four 5V DC fans"* **Where** do you wish to connect them? If you wish to connect them to GND, that's OK (but not useful). The 5V bus?... Have you checked the specifications for the RPi's 5V supply? Asking a [good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: I wrote, "I was thinking to connect them directly to the Pi-Plates MOTORplate (https://pi-plates.com/motorr1/)". Which I mean connect the 4 fans to the MOTORplate..

Comment: Exactly... but ***WHERE***???

Comment: Why can you not add another supply?

Comment: Due to lack of space